# Implementing a Postfix Calculator from a file using a Stack (java)

Tags: java, file, stack

I'm having difficulty coming up with coding the algorithm necessary to accomplish this in my infix method. I'm using a pop/push method. Below is the expected input and output of my code. Here are the exact steps needed in the algorithm:

1. Input is a string which contains the infix integer expression
2. Loop from the 0th position to the last position in the input
   string

   a) Isolate a single character string from the input string

   b) If the character string is a left parenthesis "(", push it on the
   stack

   c) If the character string is a digit (integer), add it to 
   the end of the output string

   d)  If the character string is an operator (*, /, %, +, -), push it on the   stack

   e) If the character string is a right parenthesis ")", pop
   each operator off the stack, and add each operator to the end of the
   output string, until you pop a left parenthesis "(" off the stack

   3. After looping, the output string is the postfix expression

   So my question is, how do I implement part c and part e into my code.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

The file itself contains:

```
(5)(1+1)((9/3)-2)(9-(3/2))(1+(4-(9*(6/(5%7)))))((1+4)-(((9*6)/5)%7))(((1+(4-9))*6)/(5%7)) ((1+(2-3))(1+(2-3)))(1+(A-3))(1@1)
```

and is supposed to output:

```
Reading from file: input13.txt

Infix expression   = (5)
Postfix expression = 5

Infix expression   = (1+1)
Postfix expression = 11+

Infix expression   = ((9/3)-2)
Postfix expression = 93/2-

Infix expression   = (9-(3/2))
Postfix expression = 932/-

Infix expression   = (1+(4-(9*(6/(5%7)))))
Postfix expression = 149657%/*-+

Infix expression   = ((1+4)-(((9*6)/5)%7))
Postfix expression = 14+96*5/7%-

Infix expression   = (((1+(4-9))*6)/(5%7))
Postfix expression = 149-+6*57%/

Infix expression   =      
ERROR:java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad character input: " "

Infix expression   = ((1+(2-3))
ERROR:java.lang.RuntimeException: Data still on stack: "("

Infix expression   = (1+(2-3)))
ERROR:java.util.EmptyStackException

Infix expression   = (1+(A-3))
ERROR:java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad character input: "A"

Infix expression   = (1@1)
ERROR:java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad character input: "@"
```

Here is my current code:

`equation` is the entire line from the file BTW

```
       public static String infix(String equation){
       //instantiate a stack of Strings
         StackInterface<String> stack = new ArrayStack<String>();
         for(int i=0;i<equation.length();i++){

            String character = equation.substring(i, i+1);
            //Having trouble with this algorithm!
           if (character == "(" ) {
             stack.push(character);

           }
            else if (character.isDigit()) {
               //add to end of outputstream
            }
            else if (character == "*") {
              stack.push(character);
            }
            else if (character == "/") {
              stack.push(character);
            }
            else if (character == "%") {
              stack.push(character);
            }
            else if (character == "+") {
              stack.push(character);
            }
            else if (character == "-") {
              stack.push(character);
            }
            /* If the character string is a right parenthesis ")", 
              pop each operator off the stack, and add each operator to the
              end of the output string, until you pop a left parenthesis
              "("  off the stack */

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `StackInterface` and `ArrayStack` from where you are using ? Apache API?? `else if (character.isDigit();)` this line will not compile.

Comment: And what *does* it output?

Comment: @immibis nothing yet, its just that else if algorithm I am having trouble writing, I having quite made a print method yet.

Comment: Which part are you stuck on? (Don't say "all of it")

Comment: @immibis Well I am having a problem figuring exactly how to deal with  whenever the character is a integer, and a ")" . I know what I have to do in the algorithm if it is a ")"  which is  "If the character string is a right parenthesis ")", pop each operator off the stack, and add each operator to the end of the output string, until you pop a left parenthesis "(" off the stack" as outlined in my comment, I just have no idea how to go about doing that.

Comment: you can check the TOP of The Stack and when you got `)` then start pop process until its not `(` (included). you can use `peek()` for it.

Comment: Is this an assignment?

Comment: @fge it seems to be. Here are the files needed: http://www.cs.nyu.edu/courses/fall13/CSCI-GA.1133-001/programs/Stacks/

Comment: With your method to read the file you will not notice any blanks.

Comment: @Soana Ah so the whitespace could become a problem? I think that's okay as in the input file, It is only one line with only 1 break which will bring back an error as planned.

Comment: But you are only reading String tokens, delimited by blanks (`scanFile.next()`), so other than counting how many tokens you read, there is no way to discover any blanks. You might want to have a look at `nextLine()` to get the whole line and not just tokens.

Comment: @Soana oops I just noticed that. Edited my code to reflect.

Comment: @Soana Do you think I should edit out my entire main and ReadFromTheFile method so that the infix method is all that's focused on?

Comment: I suggest you do this the proper way, with the Dijkstra Shunting-yard algorithm. Supporting operator precedence is required in general, and if you think it isn't required for this specific problem you might be wrong about that. It won't do any harm, in any event.